# Centos Server Crashed and wiped everything after network restart

Tags: linux, centos6, linux-networking

Using Centos 6, I modified the hosts and network file, restarted and everything has been down. Here are the steps.

modified `/etc/hosts` to update the ip from what my dedicated server seller originally had

```
173.234.60.xxx 173.234.60.xxx.rdn.srv1350.ubiquitymotion (something similar to this)
to
173.234.60.xxx domain.com (my current domain)
```

Secondly I added to my `/etc/sysconfig/network`

`GATEWAY=192.168.1.254` as the `NETWORKING` and `HOST` properties were already set

Lastly I ran `/etc/init.d/network restart` it turned off eth0 OK and that's the last I heard. Afterwards I haven't been able to connect on any ports, it seems to have cleared the whole harddrive. not sure if anyone has experienced this but I'm baffled...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely Gateway is wrong. If you have access to some other PC/Server in the same subnet (192.168.1.0/24 I assume), you can try to connect to your CentOS from it.

Comment: I can access my server through Centos rescue mode live CD but the issue now sadly is not being able to find where the server is. I tried everything on fdisk -l

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it would have cleared the hard drive. It likely just stopped being accessible due to an incorrect network setup. You will need to get direct console access or contact your server hosting company to fix it.